# A k-form is thought of as measuring the flux through an infinitesimal k-parallelepiped

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds

On the wikipedia has written "A $k$-form is thought of as measuring the flux through an infinitesimal $k$-parallelepiped." How does a $k$-form do this? if this sentence is right, then the flux of which object is measured by $k$-form?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you get hold of a copy of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's Gravity ?  They spend a lot of time explaining this point of view with great pictures.  My memory (lost my copy in a postdoctoral move somewhere) is that what is measured is the flux of the $k$-form. 

Answer (score 3):

See Theorem 1 in Anders Kock's paper
“[Differential forms as infinitesimal cochains](http://home.imf.au.dk/kock/van00.PDF)”,
which is devoted precisely to this question.
Specifically, the map b in the formula (1)
establishes an explicit bijection between differential
forms and functions on the space of infinitesimal parallelepipeds (or, equivalently, simplices)
that vanish on degenerate parallelepipeds/simplices.
The fact that this isomorphism commutes with differentials
is precisely the infinitesimal version of Stokes' formula.